# Javascript call function in html

Tags: javascript, sharepoint

I am using sharepoint 2013. I am checking infopath input values. If values == null, show popup menu. I am using method manually it's okay but calling function dynamically I can't handle. Check please. Here is my code:

```js
$(document).ready(function queryName(inputID) {
  console.log("document loaded");
  var oo = document.getElementById(inputID).value;
  if (oo == "") {
    document.getElementById(inputID).style.display = "none";
    return Uyari();
  }
  return true;
});

function Uyari() {
  swal({
    title: "Hata",
    text:
      "Üzgünüm, kişisel bilgilerini sorgularken hata oluştu, lütfen sayfayı yenileyiniz..",
    type: "warning",
    showCancelButton: false,
    confirmButtonColor: "#3085d6",
    cancelButtonColor: "#d33",
    confirmButtonText: "Sayfayı Yenile"
  }).then(result => {
    if (result.value) {
      location.reload();
      swal(
        "Yenilendi!",
        "Sayfa başarıyla yenilendi, yönlendiriliyorsunuz..",
        "success"
      );
    }
  });
}
```

```css
body {
  font-family: "Open Sans", -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, "Segoe UI",
    Roboto, Oxygen-Sans, Ubuntu, Cantarell, "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial,
    sans-serif;
}
.swal2-container {
  z-index: 9;
}
```

```html
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <title>A Pen by lakers</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/SiteAssets/style.css" />
</head>
<body>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/sweetalert2"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/promise-polyfill"></script>
  <script src="/SiteAssets/index.js"></script>
  <script>
    queryName(
      "ctl00_ctl36_g_f08fb998_3f0e_4cf4_8ff9_111130eb0e22_FormControl0_V1_I1_T5"
    );
  </script>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

What exactly is the error you are receiving?